# custom exception message in spring cloud function deployed in aws-lambda

Tags: exception, aws-lambda, error-code, spring-cloud-function

I have a java project written using spring-cloud-function and deployed in aws-lambda.

I am trying to return a custom exception with some fields in the exception message body, something like"

```
{
  reason: <exception reason>
  code: <error code>
  <some other fields>
}
```

@ExceptionHandler, that is generally used in spring boot doesn't seem to work here.

I can return the exception in the required format by creating a class for building the exception message in required format but in that case the error code will always be 200 since it will not be an exception object per se. Instead it will be my custom error object.

Is there a way I can set this up so that the above required format of exception object is returned and correct error code can be returned too?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the exception has nothing to do with Spring Boot. It's part of spring-web, so yes it would not work here since s-c-function is a general purpose framework, where the same function could be deployed and triggered via web, streaming, aws-lambda etc. .

Now, yes we had a problem returning JSON error (as you show) or object that represents the same, but that was fixed. So please update s-c-function to 3.2.3.

Comment: thanks for sharing this. However, can you please point me to a working example so that I can see how things work together?

Comment: Have you actually tried to do exactly what you describe with the newest version?

Comment: That's what I am asking. Are you saying that @ExceptionHandler is helpful starting 3.2.3 or what?

Comment: I said the complete opposite (I meant your comment about the custom object). But in reality if your function results in exception it now will be properly propagated and displayed in AWS Lambda. So technically you don't need to do anything and let any exception propagate to the framework.

Comment: The exception will be propagated. But what about the custom exception with a specific  format as shown above in the description? How will that be propagated with the correct error code? As I said I am able to propagate the custom error object. But since that's my custom error object, the error code is always 200 regardless of the actual exception.